# Contract gets out of gas on GnosisSafeProxy::fallback when sending eth from contract

Tags: safe-core

I am trying to run a function that sends ETH to a Multisig safe.

```
function withdrawAll() external onlyOwner {
   uint256 _balance = address(this).balance;
   require(payable(safeAddress).send(_balance));
}
```

I get the following error.

```
[43097] Withdraw::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [16200] FrogeNFT::withdrawAll()
    │   ├─ [2183] GnosisSafeProxy::fallback{value: 650000000000000000}()
    │   │   └─ ← EvmError: OutOfGas
    │   └─ ← EvmError: Revert
    └─ ← EvmError: Revert
```

I have created a Tenderly simulation to help
https://www.tdly.co/shared/simulation/65338102-6844-4e15-826b-11ebea0dba31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the address of the safe along with the first slot and the singleton.

You can find the singleton with the contract view method `getStorageAt(0, 1)` the safe gets the singleton in the fallback so check that for where your singleton is stored at

```
let _singleton := and(sload(0), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
```

Here is the example of the `accessList`

```
[
  [
    "0x4d1e64484f31b91b22627f7888ac9587e6d86072",
    [
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552",
    []
  ]
]
```

My simulated transaction https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer/fork/dcc2efab-150f-4f71-a549-479f15255a9f/simulation/05662d72-30bf-45a2-a978-ab4cc5485c39

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the gas limit on `transfer` and `send` functions, which is 2300. And the fallback of the receiver contract might be using more gas.

Use call instead.
`payable(safeAddress).call{value:balance}("");`

Comment: The contract is already deployed. Been looking at this https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40813-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe but i cant seem to get the slots aligned correctly